# How do I RUN systemctl with udev rules?

Tags: udev, tty, systemctl

I am attempting to start a service with systemctl using a udev rule.

`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Belkin USB PDA Adapter", ATTRS{serial}=="778452", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service"`

syslog on the failure

```
Mar 23 18:04:39 pi4 kernel: [289664.631249] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Mar 23 18:04:39 pi4 kernel: [289664.781515] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=050d, idProduct=0109, bcdDevice= 1.02
Mar 23 18:04:39 pi4 kernel: [289664.781534] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 23 18:04:39 pi4 kernel: [289664.781550] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Belkin USB PDA Adapter
Mar 23 18:04:39 pi4 kernel: [289664.781565] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 778452
Mar 23 18:04:39 pi4 kernel: [289664.786461] mct_u232 1-1.1:1.0: MCT U232 converter detected
Mar 23 18:04:39 pi4 kernel: [289664.786747] usb 1-1.1: MCT U232 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Mar 23 18:04:48 pi4 systemd[1]: dev-ttyUSB0.device: Job dev-ttyUSB0.device/start timed out.
Mar 23 18:04:48 pi4 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/ttyUSB0.
Mar 23 18:04:48 pi4 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Serial Getty on ttyUSB0.
Mar 23 18:04:48 pi4 systemd[1]: serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service: Job serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 23 18:04:48 pi4 systemd[1]: dev-ttyUSB0.device: Job dev-ttyUSB0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 23 18:04:48 pi4 systemd-udevd[1288]: Process '/usr/bin/systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service' failed with exit code 1.
```

Yet when I run `systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service` manually the service starts just fine. Is there something obvious I am doing wrong to RUN+= this in my udev rule?

Comment: Viewed 69 times though hayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy